# Cannot host website with system.web.extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-6

I am developing an .net 4.0 web application where I host it on IIS. The application was successfully hosted several times without the use of `<system.web.extensions>` in `web.config` file.

The application gets published without any errors, but when I try to host it using `IIS` and try to enable  `Directory Browsing` it gives out the error `The configuration section system.web,extensions cannot be read because its missing a section declaration`. I've already set it up as .net 4.0 application from the application pool but still gives the error.

Following is my `web.config` file,

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
    -->
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
          <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
    </system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
        <webServices>
          <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
          </jsonSerialization>
        </webServices>
      </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
  </configuration>
```

May I know what i'm doing wrong here..this is such a headache  and I've tried most of the resources online but all suggest to set the application pool to `.net 4.0` which I have already done..

Many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Add this to the configuration sections. Its weird that it isn't defaulted in the applicationHost.config

Comment: ahhh i need to add it to `applicationHost.config` right? am trying it now and will post back :)

Comment: Let me clarify. Typically this lives in the applicationHost.config so you don't need to set it in your app.config, however if it is missing you can add it in either location.

Answer (score 3):

If you upload 4.0 application on IIS with app pool which is set for 2.0 - 3.5 Integrated Pipeline then you will see the error about missing a section declaration for extension.

You need to set on IIS the app pool for 4.0-4.5 Integrated Pipeline.

Comment: Actually this is the best and the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue by adding following configuration setting in webconfig file

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```